# Does the local family index theorem hold for compact manifolds with corners?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, index-theory

Let $\pi:X\to B$ be a submersion with closed, oriented and spin fibers of even dimension. Suppose $X$ and $B$ are compact, and let $E\to X$ be a complex vector bundle over with a Hermitian metric $g^E$ and a unitary connection $\nabla^E$. By putting metrics and connections on the vertical bundle and the spinor bundle associated to $\pi:X\to B$ (ignoring the details here), the local family index theorem (let say under the kernel bundle assumption) states that
$$d\widehat{\eta}=\int_{X/B}\widehat{A}(\nabla^{T^VX})\wedge\textrm{ch}(\nabla^E)-\textrm{ch}(\nabla^{\ker(\mathsf{D})}),$$
where $\mathsf{D}$ is the spin Dirac operator twisted by $E\to X$ and $\widehat{\eta}$ is the Bismut-Cheeger eta form.

Now let say $X$ and $B$ are compact manifolds with corners. Does the theorem still hold? If it doesn't hold, what could go wrong?

I am not aware of any paper having such a statement.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to give a concrete reference for what theorem you are referring to.  Or to state the proposition you are curious about.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thanks. I added the statement I was asking.

Comment: It is ok to assume that $B$ has corners. But if the fibres have corners as well, you would need boundary conditions that are compatible at the corners. I suggest looking at Bunke's paper [Index theory, eta forms, and Deligne cohomology](http://www.ams.org/books/memo/0928/).

Comment: @SebastianGoette Thanks. I was considering $X=X'\times\Delta^2$ and $B=B'\times\Delta^2$, where $X'$ and $B'$ are closed manifolds and $\Delta^2$ is the standard 2-simplex. So the fibers are closed manifolds. When you say it's ok to assume $B$ has corners, is it okay for both $X$ and $B$ to have corners? Also, thanks for mentioning the paper by Bunke. Well, it is certainly not an easy read.

Comment: I am sure the family index theorem holds if the fibres are closed and all structure (bundle connection, vertical metric, coefficients of the operator ...) extend smoothly to $\partial X$ and $\partial B$. All the infinite-dimensional analysis in the proof is concerned with the fibrewise operators. The base $B$ enters more or less only through its exterior algebra.

Comment: @SebastianGoette I see. Thank you very much~